# What is the Plugin Syntax for Facebook SDK For PhoneGap Build

Tags: facebook, plugins, sdk, phonegap-build, phonegap

ALL

I have searched long and hard all over the internet for the syntax for Facebook SDK to be used for PhoneGap Build via build.phonegap.com

Just like there is  for SplashScreen what us the plugin syntax for Facebook SDK that I can add to my config.xml

I sincerely appreciate the correct answer to this.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I have found the syntax I was looking for:

Below it is:

```
<plugin spec="https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4.git" source="git" > 
    <param name="APP_ID" value="---YOUR APP ID----" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="---YOUR APP NAME---" />
</plugin>
```